# Change SSH Port Using Saltstack

Tags: saltstack

I have a server with a "standalone" minion installed and configured. I've been able to make lots of changes to my server with salt but I can't figure out how to configure my ssh server.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$ cat sshd.sls 
include:
  - openssh

sshd_config:
  Port: 1234
```

I have also downloaded the `openssh` formula into my `/srv/formulas` directory and updated my `file_roots` in my `/etc/salt/minion` dir:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
    - /srv/formulas/openssh-formula
```

And finally I have the following in my `top.sls` file:

```
base:
  '*':
    - users
    - sshd
```

Then I get this when I apply my state:

```
$ sudo salt-call state.apply --local
local:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    State 'sshd_config' in SLS 'sshd' is not formed as a list
```

I've looked at the documentation for the [openssh formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula) but I don't see how I'm misusing the API. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing it wants the `-` in `- Port: 1234`

Comment: The error indicates that this bit of YAML in `sshd_config` is being interpreted as a Salt state, not as a Salt pillar. You need to add that setting to a file in one of the `pillar_roots` directories, not in the `file_roots` directories.

Answer (score 1):

The [openssh formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula) support additional configuration and customization through [Pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/pillar/index.html#pillar).

In you configured your Pillar to use `/srv/pillar`, you can create a simple `/srv/pillar/top.sls` file with the following contents:

```
base:
  '*':
    - sshd
```

This top file associates the `sshd.sls` file to all minions. Now the `/srv/pillar/sshd.sls` file needs to be populated:

```
sshd_config:
  Port: 1234
```

Examples of all available options can be found in a file named `pillar.example` in the root directory of [openssh formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula) repository.

There is no need for creating a custom sshd state if you use the [openssh formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula). Your `/srv/salt/top.sls` should look similar to this:

```
base:
  '*':
    - users
    - openssh
```